# Simple compilation fails under Maven, succeeds with javac

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple Maven project that includes one file, App.java, containing

```
package com.foo;

public class App 
{
    private Long wrapper;

    public long getlong() {
        if (null != wrapper) {
            return wrapper;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

(You can duplicate this by using the Maven in 5 minutes project creation and replacing App.java with the above).

`mvn compile` produces

```
.../foo/App.java:[9,12] incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Long
required: long
```

while navigating to the directory and running `javac App.java` produces no errors. Anybody know what's up? (I assume that Maven uses whatever version of Java is installed on my box; in any case, that's 1.6.0_21. Thanks.

Comment: What does `mvn version` report for the JDK version being used?

Comment: `mvn -V compile` also reports 1.6.0_21.

Comment: Interestingly, all of the above occurs on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. When I do exactly the same thing on my Mac OS box, the Maven compile works properly as well. In this case, `mvn -V compile` reports 1.6.0_41.

Comment: Are you using openJDK on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably compiling with a `source` or `target` version of 1.4. You will need to configure the compiler plugin to compile for a higher version. See ["How do I set up Maven so it will compile with a target and source JVM of my choice?"](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#Compiling-J2SE-5) and ["Setting the `-source` and `-target` of the Java Compiler"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html):

```
  ...
  <build>
  ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  ...
  </build>
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that somehow I was getting the 1.4 JDK, but could not figure out how. Thanks again.