# Getting compile errors on protobuf generated java file - how to compile?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, javac

Title says it all;

"mvn compile" produces tons of errors, here's the first:

*[ERROR] $HOME/workspace/JavaExamplePBServiceCall/src/main/java/example/ServicecallPiqi.java:[13,23] error: ';' expected*

manual compilation produces 100 errors, here is the first:

*javac -cp $HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar ServicecallPiqi.java*

```
ServicecallPiqi.java:535: error: cannot find symbol
    public static com.google.protobuf.Parser<params> PARSER =
                                     ^
  symbol:   class Parser
  location: package com.google.protobuf
```

Beginning of ServicecallPiqi.java:

```
package example;
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: pb_piqi_out/servicecall.piqi.proto

public final class ServicecallPiqi {
  private ServicecallPiqi() {}
  public static void registerAllExtensions(
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
  }
  /**
   * Protobuf enum {@code cast_type}
   */
  public enum cast_type implements
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ OFFENDING line
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaExamplePBServiceCall</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>PBServiceCallExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How do I get it to compile?

Comment: When you are getting "cannot find symbol" errors, that's because you aren't including any library which defines that symbol.  If you want people to troubleshoot your compilation errors, you need to include the pom.xml you are trying to build from.

Comment: I added my pom.xml, please review :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `Parser` classes have been added only after version 2.5.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/CHANGES.txt), but you're declaring dependency on protobuf v2.4.1.

You're probably compiling your `.proto` files with a later version of the compiler than what are the runtime classes you're adding to your POM file.

Update your dependency / downgrade your `protoc` compiler and everything will work just fine.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason for using JUnit 3 and not JUnit 4? Version 4.11 is the lastest one as of now.

Comment: It was just the default pom generated by the archetype:generate command. I chose this version of protobuf because that's what protoc --version ouputs: "libprotoc 2.4.1"; perhaps there's a different versioning between the protoc compiler and ... some "other component"?

Comment: Also, even after editing the pom.xml, it compiles with javac -cp $HOME/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar ServicecallPiqi.java, but not with mvn compile

Comment: I fixed it! This was the key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303216/simple-compilation-fails-under-maven-succeeds-with-javac